# MySQL Stored Procedure Rollback on first If-else statement, if second if-else statement fails

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like some help with MySQL Stored Procedure below, When the first If else statement goes through, and the second one errors, it shows the error message that I input in the ELSE statement but I would like to rollback the first If else statement if the second one error's out. How would I do this?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Example()
BEGIN
  SET @countOfTable = (select count(*) from Db1.tbl1);
  IF @countOfTable > 0
  THEN
    INSERT INTO db1.tblLog
        (
        BatchStoreId,
        Origin
        )
    SELECT 
        (SELECT DISTINCT SomeID FROM db1.tbl1) as SomeId,
        (SELECT Origin FROM db1.tblKey WHERE Origin = 'ThisText') as Origin;
  ELSE
    SELECT 'table is empty!' as ErrorMessage;
  End if;
  SET @countOpp = (SELECT count(*) FROM db1.tbl2),
    @MR = (SELECT DISTINCT SomeID FROM db1.tbl1),
    @Opp = (SELECT DISTINCT OtherIDFROM db1.tbl2);
  IF @countOpp > 0 and @MR = @Opp
  THEN
    INSERT INTO db1.tbllog
      (
       SomeID,
       Origin
      )
    SELECT
      (SELECT DISTINCT SomeID FROM db1.tbl2) as SomeID,
      (SELECT Origin FROM db1.tblkey WHERE Origin = 'Secondary Text') as Origin;
  ELSE
    SELECT 'SomeID's Do Not Match in tables db1.tbl1 and db1.tbl2' as ErrorMessage;
  End if;
END;
```

Comment: Start a transaction. Commit it if everything succeeds, roll it back if there's an error.

Comment: I would input the Start Transaction after the BEGIN and the ROLLBACK before the End If or after and than the COMMIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `START TRANSACTION;`  and then on you else statement, use a `ROLLBACK` and then, at the end of your procedure, execute a `commit`. I did a simple sample of how it should look like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_example()
BEGIN   
    -- Starting the transaction
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `test`.`owner` (`name`) VALUES ('Insert Cubias');
IF 1 > 2 THEN
    INSERT INTO `test`.`owner` (`name`) VALUES ('McCubo');
ELSE
    SELECT 'Rollback transaction' as ErrorMessage;
    -- No records will be inserted
    ROLLBACK;
End if;

-- commit changes to database
COMMIT;
END;
$$
```

You should take a look at the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html for further information.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you!! I got it!! THANK YOU! I added the rollback in the else for both if else statements and got what the desired result. Thank you @barmar as well!